# Ubuntu 18.10 Mouse declick issue

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dell, 18.10, xps

System: Dell XPS 13 (9370)

Computer does not seem to be registering the de-click action on the touchpad, or when using a physical mouse ie when editing text a completed click with a following mouse movement has the action of selecting the text from the the initial click location to the final cursor point.

Occurs in Spyder, RStudio, and IDLE. Also seems to effect the selection of programs from the favorites tray  Instead of opening, they will be highlighted and dragged. Similar or same issue as:

[Left mouse is held down after single click, but only in certain programs (RStudio)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1053942/922715)

[Mouse acting like left button is held down in some programs](https://askubuntu.com/q/1083895/922715)

My current remedy is to restart computer.

Would have added this information as a comment to the linked posts, but as a new contributor, I am not able to do this and with the different versions of Ubuntu the problem is presenting in, may be (but probably not) a different issue.

Comment: You really should just make this a new question.  So, do you have a touchscreen?  I ran into a few issues with my dell inspiron and interaction between the mouse and a touchscreen.

Comment: Touchscreen is currently on, I'll try to turn it off and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you can do it in bios that's best.   You may have to disable it with xinput

Comment: If it needs to be done outside of BIOS, I do have some scripts that can disable the touch screen that I use.

Comment: See [https://askubuntu.com/a/986453/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/986453/283721) and [https://askubuntu.com/a/985609/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/985609/283721)

Answer (score 1):

It is, like Charles suggested a touch screen issue, which seems to be remediable by tapping the screen a few times.