# Ubuntu 17.10, jumping keys while typing. if touch pad is enabled

Tags: touchpad, 17.10

I know this is a known bug in ubuntu 17.10. But I want to know is anyone find a way to solve this annoying issue.

```
Laptop: Acer E 15 E5-575G
Nvidia 940MX
ENV: Xorg Gnome
```

I am forced to disable touch pad while typing.

If anyone have find a way to solve this issue please tell me.

Comment: I solved it for myself, by disabling the touchscreen.  This allows the disable-while-typing setting to work properly in my system.  Please see [https://askubuntu.com/a/986453/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/986453/283721)

Comment: Mr. Charles Green,  I will try and let you know sir.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that this worked for you